# Gitlab CI - Run the job on merge request to specific branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want configure my CI with a following condition :

- When i create a merge request
- And this target branch is develop

My job runs.

I don't find a documentation for this specific job.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After severals hours in Gitlab CI documentation i found this solution.

```yaml
unit_test:
    stage: test
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
    script:
        - echo "Test running"
        - ...
```